# Allow class to modify singleton only if it has implemented interface

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture

I have a singleton that's acting as a core setup and manager for a large application.  I want to restrict write access to callers outside the singleton but still allow it only if they've implemented a specific interface I define (e.g., `ICoreModifier`)

The desired outcome is below:

```cs
public class Core
{
    // singleton code omitted

    int Property { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class A : ICoreModifier
{
    // implemented ICoreModifier so things are okay
    Core.GetInstance().Property = 1;
}
```

```cs
public class B
{
    // No ICoreModifier implementation so this results in compile or runtime error
    Core.GetInstance().Property = 1;
}
```

However, there's two issues I'm running into with this.

1. I'm having trouble coming up with what would actually go on the interface.  This tells me I must be following the wrong design structure.  I'm open to alternative approaches. I've been thinking about some sort of `Lock` and `Unlock` kind of method implementation requirement, but delegating write access to the person asking to write sounds like a *bad idea* and probably wouldn't even work.
2. Ideally, I'd like for this to be a compile time error rather than runtime.  If that's not possible that's okay, but I'm still not quite sure how I go about doing a runtime check.  My current thinking is to use reflection, but that seems messy and not very robust.

I've considered inheritance as well, but my understanding is that inheritance is with regard to **is-a** relationships.  The classes getting write access are not cores themselves.  This is why the **can-do** relationship interfaces provide seem most appropriate to me here.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You could, in each setting, verify that the caller is implementing that interface. I'm not sure this would be considered good practice, though. 1) Get the caller information (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/caller-information) 2) Look up that type with reflection 3) Get the interfaces that that types implements 4) Throw if it does not implement ICoreModifier. This leaves the checking inside your code, as opposed to having the caller need to worry about it.

Comment: @Steve I have been considering this as an approach.  Like you said though, it's probably not best practice.  The downside with this is that it's probably very easy to break if changes need to be made in the future since a lot of this is runtime specific.

Comment: I don't know why you think you want to do this, but I do know that it's a mistake.

Comment: @MattTimmermans I'm starting to think this as well, but are there any key things you're thinking that I may not be considering as being the main issue with my described approach?  So far, I'm thinking that I should just have an initialize method for setup at the start of the application and then lockdown the core class after setup.  I'm starting to find that there may not be a great reason to provide complete write access for everything and instead just provide specific write access on an as needed basis in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to constrain behavior based on what the caller is in C#, as opposed to adding behavior *to* the caller.

That said, you could pass the caller itself and only allow the update if the caller is an `ICoreModifier`. It is clunky and there isn't anything that prevents the caller from simply instantiating a concrete instance of `ICoreModifier`, but it does give you the compile time check you are looking for:

```
public interface ICoreModifier { }

public class Core
{
    // singleton code omitted

    int Property { get; set; }
    
    public void ModifyProperty(ICoreModifier callerInstance, int newValue)
    {
        if (callerInstance is null) return;
        Property = newValue;
    }
}

public class A : ICoreModifier
{
    public A()
    {
        // this succeeds
        new Core().ModifyProperty(this, 10);
    }
}

public class B
{
    public B()
    {
        // this throws a compile time error since this cannot be converted to ICoreModifier
        new Core().ModifyProperty(this, 10);
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively (and preferably), you can use namespacing to restrict access to Core by making it internal, and exposing abstraction layers that can be inherited by the client classes:

```
namespace Core.Internal
{
    internal static class Core
    {
        // singleton code omitted

        static internal int Property { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class CoreModifier
    {
        public void ModifyProperty(int newValue) => Core.Property = newValue; 
    }
    
    public class CoreReader
    {
        public int Property = Core.Property;
    }
}

public class A : Core.Internal.CoreModifier
{
    public A()
    {
        // this succeeds
        ModifyProperty(10);
    }
}

public class B : Core.Internal.CoreReader
{
    public B()
    {
        // this throws a compile time error
        ModifyProperty(10);
        
        // you can however read the property
        Console.WriteLine(Property);
    }
}
```

---

And finally, just for completeness' sake, you can always inspect the stack frame to check the calling method type. However, this is not advisable for a number of reasons, not the least of which is that the caller can be potentially optimized away. This implementation uses caching based on caller attributes to identify the call site to hide the cost of the `StackFrame` reflection for subsequent calls:

```
public interface ICoreModifier { }

public static class Core
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, bool> s_permissionCache = new();
    
    public static int Property { get; private set; }
    
    public static void ModifyProperty(
        int newValue, 
        [CallerFilePathAttribute] string filePath = default, 
        [CallerMemberNameAttribute] string callerMemberName = default, 
        [CallerLineNumberAttribute] int lineNumber = default)
    {
        var key = $"{filePath}_{callerMemberName}_{lineNumber}";
        if (s_permissionCache.TryGetValue(key, out bool cachedValue))
        {
            if (!cachedValue) return;
            
            Property = newValue;
            return;
        }
        
        var type = new StackFrame(1).GetMethod().DeclaringType;
        
        if (!type.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ICoreModifier)))
        {
            s_permissionCache.TryAdd(key, false);
            return;
        }
        
        Property = newValue;
        s_permissionCache.TryAdd(key, true);
    }
}

public class A : ICoreModifier
{   
    public void ModifyProperty(int newValue) => Core.ModifyProperty(newValue);
}

public class B
{
    public void ModifyProperty(int newValue) => Core.ModifyProperty(newValue);
}
```

You can test this with the following:

```
var a = new A();
a.ModifyProperty(10);
Console.WriteLine(Core.Property);

a.ModifyProperty(12);
Console.WriteLine(Core.Property);

var b = new B();
b.ModifyProperty(14);
Console.WriteLine(Core.Property);
```

This prints

```
10
12
12
```

since the call to B does not meet the implemented interface criteria.

Comment: I'm going to mark this one as answered since the second solution you provided is closest to what I was thinking I should go for based on my original question, however, I'm now finding that my current approach likely isn't the best and needs some more thought.  I'm mainly leaving this comment here for posterity sake.

Answer (score 1):

You can have an interface with nothing in it, it would be what's called a marker interface.  I definitely would *not* delegate lock/unlock to the client.

I think this is better handled with inheritance, but not for Core, it should be for a PropertyProvider class which provides all the defaults.  New PropertyProviders can be provided which overrides the properties as needed.  This meets the is-a relationship.

This is nice because you mark properties as sealed when you don't want to allow users to override them, and private if you don't even want to share them.

Comment: Is what you're describing with the provider classes known as the observer pattern or is this a different pattern you're talking about?

Comment: It's not really the observer pattern, It's just a Factory pattern + Dependency Injection to pass in the parameter class.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to check whether the class implements interface and based on this you can your code. It can be done through operator `is`.

[As msdn says about operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/is) `is`:

> The is operator checks if the result of an expression is compatible
> with a given type.

Let me show an example:

```
public interface ICoreModifier { }


public class A : ICoreModifier
{
    public void SetProperty() 
    {
        if (this is ICoreModifier)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(A)} - You can edit");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(A)} - There are no rights to edit");
        }
    }
}

public class B
{
    public void SetProperty()
    {
        if (this is ICoreModifier)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(B)} - You can edit");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(B)} - There are no rights to edit");
        }
    }
}
```

and the above code snippet can be run like this:

```
A a = new A();
a.SetProperty(); // A - You can edit

B b= new B();
b.SetProperty(); // B - You can edit
```

**Another solution:**

I would like to share with another solution that I would stick with.
Let's create abstractions to know whether it is eligible to edit your singleton class:

```
public interface IRightsModifier
{
    bool CanEdit();
}

public interface ICoreModifier : IRightsModifier
{
    void SetProperty();
}
```

and then its concrete implementations:

```
public class A : ICoreModifier
{
    public bool CanEdit() => true;    

    public void SetProperty() 
    {
        if (CanEdit())
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(A)} - You can edit");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(A)} - There are no rights to edit");
        }
    }
}

public class B : ICoreModifier
{
    public bool CanEdit() => false;

    public void SetProperty()
    {
        if (CanEdit())
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(B)} - You can edit");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(B)} - There are no rights to edit");
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can put the above classes in any list and run their methods:

```
List<IRightsModifier> coreModifiers = new List<IRightsModifier>()
{
    new A(),
    new B()
};

foreach (ICoreModifier coreModifier in coreModifiers)
{
    coreModifier.SetProperty();
}
```